# My simple app is skipping a lot of frames. (Imageview and Imagebutton)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm extremely new to Android programming. Right now I'm building a *very* simple app so i can get the hang of things.

Basically i have:
- Background
- `ImageView`
- `ImageButton`.

Every time I click the `ImageButton`, it cycles through a list of images I have stored in an array. However I'm ending up skipping a lot of frames.

```
    private static ImageButton button;
    private static ImageView current;
    private int index;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2};

    public void buttonClick() {
        current = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        current.setImageResource(images[index]);
                        if(index == (images.length - 1)) {
                            index = 0;
                        }
                        else {
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Any idea what is causing it to skip frames, and what I can do to fix it? Is it because my image files are too big? They are about 788kb each and 1920x1120.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must be doing it off the ui thread.
2. Images/Bitmaps should be efficiently loaded.
3. Refer example on official page: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The size is the image is probably causing the skipping of frames. Try using smaller images to verify that your images are the problem.

Comment: Reducing the image size helps, but the more i reduce the worse it looks. Is there any way to make it work with high resolution pictures? On higher res phones it looks considerably worse.

Comment: May be you could try to decode bitmap off the UIThread and only load the image when the bitmap has been decoded.